Init protocolKit error
I am trying to init 1 protocolKit but am getting error. This my code
    const address = await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);

    const signer = (await provider.getSigner(address[0])) as any;
   
    const protocolKitOwner1 = await Safe.init({
      provider: RPC_URL,
      signer,
      safeAddress: SAFE_ADDRESS,
    });```

And when running the above code there will be the following error:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: invalid private key (argument="privateKey", value="[ REDACTED ]", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.13.1)
    at makeError (chunk-6KOMF32J.js?v=9adc953b:566:19)
    at assert (chunk-6KOMF32J.js?v=9adc953b:587:15)
    at assertArgument (chunk-6KOMF32J.js?v=9adc953b:592:7)
    at new _BaseWallet (chunk-6KOMF32J.js?v=9adc953b:24697:39)
    at new _Wallet (chunk-6KOMF32J.js?v=9adc953b:26646:9)
    at SafeProvider.getExternalSigner (chunk-6KOMF32J.js?v=9adc953b:62048:36)
    at SafeContract_v1_3_0.init (chunk-6KOMF32J.js?v=9adc953b:59949:111)
    at getSafeContractInstance (chunk-6KOMF32J.js?v=9adc953b:61859:34)
    at async getSafeContract (chunk-6KOMF32J.js?v=9adc953b:59270:28)
    at async _ContractManager._ContractManager_initializeContractManager2 (chunk-6KOMF32J.js?v=9adc953b:62498:45)


The signer const seems to be of a different type than expected by the init function. The function expects a private key: https://docs.safe.global/sdk/protocol-kit#initialize-the-protocol-kit

Is there any way to get the signer without using the user's privateKey?

In the document it is written: signer: This is an optional parameter. It should be the provider's address you want to use or a private key. If not set, it will try to fetch a connected account from the provider. But when using the user's address, it gives an error that the inavlid account.

this code:
const protocolKitOwner1 = await Safe.init({       provider: RPC_URL,       signer:OWNER_1_ADDRESS,       safeAddress: SAFE_ADDRESS,     });

Error: invalid account
at JsonRpcProvider.getSigner (chunk-6KOMF32J.js?v=9adc953b:21893:15)
at async SafeContract_v1_3_0.init (chunk-6KOMF32J.js?v=9adc953b:59949:87)
at async getSafeContractInstance (chunk-6KOMF32J.js?v=9adc953b:61859:7)
at async getSafeContract (chunk-6KOMF32J.js?v=9adc953b:59270:28)
at async _ContractManager._ContractManager_initializeContractManager2 (chunk-6KOMF32J.js?v=9adc953b:62498:45)
at async _ContractManager.init (chunk-6KOMF32J.js?v=9adc953b:62468:9)
